# Accessing lab test results if younger than 18

Tags: united-states, health

Quest Diagnostics claims that "Lab test results are available to patients 18 years and older" in the written email that follows an account creation on their website.

Why does Quest have that policy?

Is there any law that could require Quest to provide results to a minor, in spite of that policy? I am mostly interested in California and Massachusetts.

---

I did try to ask Quest, but they are so irresponsive to my requests that I reported them as infringing HIPAA regulations to the [proper authorities, viz. Office for Civil Rights](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31). Also, I'd rather refer to the law than to some customer service.

Comment: Have you asked Quest why they have that policy?  And what, if any, laws cover access to medical test results by minors?

Comment: @feetwet I did ask. They won't reply to my emails, and face-to-face in the lab simply said they don't know. (thanks for the edit!)

Comment: @feetwet Quest is so irresponsive that I reported them as infringing HIPAA regulations to the [proper authorities, viz. Office for Civil Rights](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31).