# What is the processing time for a HIPAA complaint filed with Office for Civil Rights?

Tags: united-states, health

What is the processing time for a [HIPAA complaint filed with Office for Civil Rights](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31)?

I filed one two months ago (a lab who performed a blood test on a patient failed to send the results to the patient no later than 30 days from the date of patient's request), but I haven't heard back from the Office for Civil Rights.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the processing time of a complaint is not a legal question - but rather one that concerns the bureaucratic processes that govern the organization. It should really be asked with the organization itself.

Comment: @Zizouz212 http://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says "Dealing with legal professionals" and "Legal process " are on-topic.

Comment: But is this legal process, which I view as something for the courts? Hmm... Sounds like a good discussion for meta :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 sure http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/380/31